# What's the best way to instruct the network to run a Windows Service during a specified time interval?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, group-policy, service, windows-service

Windows 7 Search Indexing service is [causing some problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/28209/why-am-i-getting-file-in-use-by-another-user-and-application-sharing-violation) on our network.  We get a ton of use out of it, but can no longer run it during the day while users are actively working.  Because search will actually work even when the indexing service is off (it will simply search an outdated index), I figure we can turn the service on for a couple hours in the middle of the night to update the user's indexes and then turn it off again.

The problem I face is finding the best way to do this through group policy.

- Windows Server 2008
- Windows 7 Client PCs

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider disabling indexer backoff (the process by which the indexer "senses" system load and slows itself down). Some people find that allowing the indexer to run at full steam, instead of throttled, can actually improve performance. The Group Policy setting for disabling indexer backoff lives in "Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Search", and is called "Disable indexer backoff".

Failing that, you can try and use the "Task Scheduler" to stop and restart the search index service. I'd try it on a couple of machines first, and, if the intended effect is achieved, deploy the task to a group of machines via a Group Policy Startup Script. The [command-line syntax to schedule a task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx) isn't too bad, and all the task would need to do is invoke a `net stop wsearch` or `net start wsearch`.

Comment: Thanks Evan.  Giving the "indexer backoff" setting a try before moving to the actual stating and stopping of the service.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: also note that updating the file server to server 2008 r2 will allow clients to use the index on the server rather than having to index the share on their own